# why is the "not" operator considered an operator

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

an assertion as i understand it is, a claim. so, something like "i like jello". It can be false or true. The "not" operator switches the boolean value of a statement. so if statement x was true it switches it to false and vise-versa. i think this is done by **claiming** statement x is **false**. so, if it was false to begin with the claim becomes "statement x is false" which is true. however, if it was true the claim becomes "statement x is false" which is false. so, my question is, isn't the **not** operator an assertion?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Exactly because [when applied to a statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) $P$ it "produces" a new statement $\lnot P$ with the opposite truth value. An [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) in mathematics is a function which takes zero or more input values (called operands) to a well-defined output value.

Comment: "Not" is an operator because it takes one claim/assertion and produces a new claim/assertion (with the opposite truth value). Just like the negative sign is an operator because it.takes one number and produces a new number.

Answer (score 1):

I think what is tripping you up may be that "not" is unary while "and" and "or", the other main logical operators, are binary. The "not" operator creates an assertion to the same extent that "and" can create an assertion from two other ones. If we have two statements $X$ and $Y$, the statement $X \wedge Y$ is asserting that both $X$ and $Y$ are true, while $\neg X$ is asserting that $X$ is false. At the end of the day, these are just the building blocks of statements that may or may not be true.

**Edit.** As an extra, I found it useful early on to think of these operators as functions. The "not" function takes a proposition and returns another proposition (its negation). The "or" function takes two propositions $X$ and $Y$ and returns the proposition "$X$ or $Y$".

Comment: does that mean 'ands' and 'ors' are also assertions to an extent ?

Comment: They are not assertions in and of themselves, but they create new propositions from propositions that already exist. Does that help?

Comment: yes. for example x and y = true creates the new claim x = true and y = true. the reason i even care about them is because i heard the difference between by-conditional and equivalence statements is one of them is an operation while the other is an assertion.